# PHP Cron job consuming memory

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, cron

I am calling a MYSQL function from the PHP controller in Codeigniter. When I execute the controller function through browser by mentioning the URL all works fine and memory consumption is not significant.

BUT when I use the same link in a cronjob it consumes so much memory. Effectively it consumes 99% of the 4GB server memory within 2-3 hours when executing cron every 4 minutes.

Could you please advise a solution for this.

Comment: Are you closing the connection after each use?

Comment: Check if the cron jobs actually finish or if they are still running in the background.

Comment: Question does the code run it within the 4 minutes always? And what "program" are you using to execute the php url in the cronjob, with other words show us the cronjob line/rule

Comment: @JayBlanchard could you please advise how to close the connection after each run. I am running the cron every 4 minutes. Actually the underlying database procedure takes only 20-30 seconds to complete. So happy to stop the process after every processing and start after 4 minutes.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson could you please advise how to check if the cron job actually finished. I am sure it's not within 4 minutes and the new process is kicked off while the previous one is still running.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Actually the code takes less than 20-30 seconds to complete but when running the same link through cron it's consuming all the memory over a period of time. Syntax: */4**** wget https://url/php_function >>var/log/cron.log 2>&1

Comment: Yes i wondering if wget downloads everything and keeps it's in memory it's clear you need to contents as log.. `wget --spider` what mine other (deleted) comment was about will then offcource not work.. You could try `php -r 'echo <php_code>' >>var/log/cron.log 2>&1` and replace `<php_code>` with curl or file_get_contents

Comment: .. also when the PHP code in the cronjob only does database work your are better off using a MySQL Event (MySQL's "cronjobs")

Comment: Run the script from the command line with the same user as the cron job uses and see if it is slow then as well. There's no reason for a script to be slower through cron than through a web server. If anything, it should go faster (without the overhead of the web server). You should also explicitly set the [max execution time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) to be something sensible (depending on your needs) so the script won't live for too long. Also, if the script takes longer than 4 min, then you might not need to start another script that soon?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Answer (score -1):

The problem I feel is not in MySQL query but in the execution of the total query for one complete cycle . You have set the time to every 4 minutes , so what I think that after 4 minutes the previous processes exists and a new process is getting started , ultimately so many processes are running it is consuming the server memory . Kindly increase the time gap and test .

Comment: I have now changed the frequency to 1 hour. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Any change afterward ?